# Размер массива numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Подскажите пожалуйста, ответ на вопрос по фото ниже.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я не понимаю: он показывает первую цифру 2, по логике это 2 строчки, а столбцов  - не пойму это сколько. Хотя, по логике, наверно, правильно что сам массив размером 1 на 2.

Где правда, объясните пожалуйста.

Comment: Это одномерный массив размера 2.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy тоесть я правильно понимаю, что (2,) эквивалентно (1, 2)?

Comment: Нет. Это просто двойка, одинокая.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy а есть у такой размерность название, просто я пытаюсь понять как такие массивы скалярно перемножать ,куча ошибок в коде.

Comment: Это одномерный массив размера 2. "Одномерный" - одно измерение. "Два" - размер этого измерения. Вектор длины два. Массив длины два.

Comment: Задайте вопрос чётко. Что вы делаете? Что хотите получить? Что не получается? Какая ошибка?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Я вроде теперь разобрался, спасибо вам большое, очень благодарен)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы была понятна разница:

```py
import numpy as np

a1 = np.array([1, 2])
print(a1)
print(a1.shape)
print('-' * 5)

a2 = np.array([[1, 2]])
print(a2)
print(a2.shape)
print('-' * 5)

a3 = np.array([[1], [2]])
print(a3)
print(a3.shape)

assert all(a2[0] == a1)
assert all(a3[:,0] == a1)
```

Вывод:

```
[1 2]
(2,)
-----
[[1 2]]
(1, 2)
-----
[[1]
 [2]]
(2, 1)
```

У вас **одномерный** массив длины 2. **Размер массива всегда возвращается в виде кортежа**, даже если измерение всего одно. Кортеж в питоне описывается скобками, внутри которых должна быть хотя бы одна запятая. `(2,)` - **кортеж** из одного элемента `2`.

Другие два массива, которые я привёл для сравнения - **двумерные**. Первый имеет одну строку и два столбца, а второй наоборот - две строки и один столбец. Форма `shape` у них соответствующая.

Из двумерного массива можно сделать одномерный, если извлечь нужную строку/столбец.